# What is the most suitable bootstrap css and js version for WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

WordPress currently loads jQuery 1.12.4 (Not the latest one) by default. Even we can over right this, it is not a good practice since many plugins may not working if we upgrade.....

Now I want to use Bootstrap. What is the most suitable bootstrap css and js version for WordPress? In other words what is the best bootstrap  version for jQuery 1.12.4.

Answer (score 0):

The version of bootstrap you use depends upon the theme you want to customize. ( though the theme will already have a version of bootstrap included in its assets).

But If you are trying to build your own theme then use the latest version  Currently [v4.0.0](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Bootstrap 4 doc:

> Bootstrap still requires jQuery 1.9.1 or higher, but you’re advised to
>   use version 3.x since v3.x’s supported browsers are the ones Bootstrap
>   supports plus v3.x has some security fixes

So if your going to use Bootstrap 3.x then jquery 1.12.x will be fine.